# What is the advantage of using friend function(or class) in c++?

Tags: c++, function, friend

as we all know that friend machinism damages the encapsulation in c++. 
so in which cases must we use friend function(or class) and what is the good point of friend function?

Comment: The most common use seem to be for overloading the `operator>>` and `operator<<` functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that use is for convenience - you can just as well provide accessors (not that those don't break encapsulation) :)